# An error running my application in the Android emulator

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing Android application. There is no error in my application but, while running the application in the Android emulator it showing:

> The Application has stopped unexpectedlly please try again.

I tried number of times  but it showing same error.
Another application is running in the same emulator.

Comment: Can you paste your code here or can you explain about what your application actually do?

Comment: Thank you jignesh .while doing build project i am not getting any errors data binding  in grid

Comment: There are several reasons to generate "stopped unexpectedly" exceptions. Try to debug you application and see if any error displayed in "LogCat" window in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know there is no error in your application? If the application is being "stopped unexpectedly" then that almost always means there is a bug in your application.

Depending on what environment you are using, you should be able to connect your debugger to the android emulator and see where the application crashes, so that you can work out why it crashes.

Comment: Thank you stimut i am developing using eclipse while build project i am not getting any error.

Comment: Ah. I understand now. Having no errors when building does **not** mean there are no errors in your program. It just means the compiler knew how to make your program from the source code. But what your program actually does when it is run may be wrong and cause the program to crash. I assume you are new to programming. I suggest you ask your teacher/read the section of the book about debugging so you can find out what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

There can be one possibility...If you are defining any additional java class file and not registering it in manifest.xml as an activity.  This could be the Rosene,please check it too.